# Create a list using Python conditioning on a table column

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list which have a values which are either zero or one (if the values in the table's column is Null or not). But my list only contains ones.

```
list = []
for i in range(len(df['DefaultDate'])):
  if df['DefaultDate'][i] == 'nan':
    list.append(0)
  else:
    list.append(1)
print(list)
print(df['DefaultDate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the string "nan", not for the special NaN values.  You can replace that ENTIRE code sequence with:

```
valid = ~df['DefaultDate'].isnull()
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you compare your dataframe element with the string "nan". To check whether it is "Not a Number" (NaN) you have to compare it with numpy.nan or use .isnull() :

```
import numpy as np
list = []
for i in range(len(df['DefaultDate'])):
  if df['DefaultDate'][i] == np.nan:
    list.append(0)
  else:
    list.append(1)
print(list)
print(df['DefaultDate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.isnull()` or `.notnull()` to check. Then convert to int and use `.tolist()`.

```
df['DefaultDate'].notnull().astype(int).tolist()
```

Comment: Kindly, I would like to know what exactly astype and tolist functions will do in order to integrate to my code

Comment: notnull() returns a pandas.Series of True/False values. astype(int) converts them to 1/0. tolist() returns a list (instead of a Series)